# How to create a shell script to change the password without prompt?

Tags: shell

I want to change the password of the Unix user through a shell script, but without being prompted to enter the old password.

That means I want to provide the old and new password in the shell script itself, such that during the prompt it will read it from the script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$> echo -e -n "oldpasswd\nnewpasswd\nnewpasswd" | passwd`

Or to make things a cleaner way, write a file with your passwords

```
oldpassword
newpassword
newpassword
```

and use the following command: `$> passwd < file`

The pipe and redirection operators are replacing the standard input with either the content of the file redirected, either the output of the command piped.

Comment: Does this really work?  I'm under the illusion that the `passwd` program reads from `/dev/tty` rather than standard input, so redirecting the standard input like that doesn't achieve anything.  To get around that, you normally resort to the [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) program, which arranges to run the program with its `/dev/tty` connected to a pseudo-tty or `pty` that `expect` can drive programmatically.

Comment: Changing password for userx
Old password: sh: -n:  not found.


this is the error while running this command and goes suspended mode

Comment: It is works with -e param for echo.
`-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the `chpasswd` command (if available in your linux flavor):

```
echo 'userid:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

Or, you can cat a file listing *userid:passwd* for each account on a separate line.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e -n "newpasswd\nnewpasswd" | passwd user
```